# Calcular média, desvio padrão e coeficiente de variação em série histórica no R

Tags: r, tabela-banco-de-dados, plyr

Bom dia,

Preciso gerar a média, o desvio padrão e o coeficiente de variação do data frame abaixo, das colunas mat13 a mat16, conforme abaixo:

```
library(plyr)
co_entidade<-c(23, 40, 58, 82, 104, 171,    198, 201, 202,244)
depend<-c(2,3,4,4,4,4,4,2,3,4)
mat13<-c(42,    218,    1397,   245,    393,    283, 1053,  529,    NA, 664)
mat14<-c(44,    222,    1300,   218,    428,    246,    994,    521,    NA, 678)
mat15<-c(40,    215,    1345,   199,    411,    226,    1069,   566,    NA, 598)
mat16<-c(10,    208,    1442,   154,    425,    229,    1033,    NA,    521,552)

df<-data.frame(co_entidade, depend, mat13, mat14, mat15, mat16)
df
```

co_entidade   depend  mat13 mat14 mat15 mat16
1           23      2    42    44    40    10
2           40      3   218   222   215   208
3           58      4  1397  1300  1345  1442
4           82      4   245   218   199   154
5          104      4   393   428   411   425
6          171      4   283   246   226   229
7          198      4  1053   994  1069  1033
8          201      2   529   521   566    NA
9          202      3    NA    NA    NA   521
10         244      4   664   678   598   552

E quando eu aplico a função ddply, nenhuma das estatísticas (média, des padrão e coeficiente de variação não são calculados para cada linha (co_entidade), pegando os valores das colunas mencionada, conforme abaixo.

```
cv<-function(x){coef<-sd(x)/mean(x)*100 
return(coef)}

descrit<-ddply(df, .(co_entidade,depend, mat13, mat14, mat15, mat16), 
summarize,
         media = mean(3:6,na.rm=T),
         desvpad = sd(3:6,na.rm=T),
         coefi= cv(3:6)
)
descrit
```

Entretanto, a função que apliquei não retorna os valores corretamente por linha, conforme imagem.[image: Estatísticas da série de matrículas]

Quem puder favor ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estou escrevendo como resposta, já que não tenho reputação para comentar ^_^.

Eu não estou entendendo a sua pergunta. Você quer agrupar o `df` por `co_entidade`, e pegar as estatísticas de `mat13:mat16`, correto?

Se for isso, julgo que `mat13:mat16` são uma mesma variável, que vou chamar de `mat_tipo` com um `mat_valor`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    gather(mat_tipo, mat_valor, mat13:mat16) %>% 
    group_by(co_entidade) %>% 
    summarise(
        média_mat = mean(mat_valor, na.rm = T),
        desv_mat = sd(mat_valor, na.rm = T),
        cv_mat = (desv_mat/média_mat)*100
        )

# A tibble: 10 x 4
co_entidade média_mat  desv_mat    cv_mat
<dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1          23   34.0000 16.083117 47.303287
2          40  215.7500  5.909033  2.738833
3          58 1371.0000 61.735997  4.502990
4          82  204.0000 38.305787 18.777347
5         104  414.2500 15.986974  3.859257
6         171  246.0000 26.191602 10.646993
7         198 1037.2500 32.376689  3.121397
8         201  538.6667 24.006943  4.456735
9         202  521.0000        NA        NA
10         244  623.0000 58.799093  9.43805
```

Note a ultima variável que crio na função `summarise`, o coeficiente de variação. Posso referenciar variáveis recém criadas na criação de outras.

Comment: Mas viu, recomendo transicionar do mundo do `plyr` para o mundo do `dplyr` + `tidyr` já que o `plyr` não é mais mantido/desenvolvido. Sem falar que eu acho a API do `dplyr` + `tidyr` bem mais tranquila de se entender e ler.

Comment: Guilherme, é isso mesmo que preciso, vou testar os seus comandos, se puder veja o coeficiente de variação também.

Comment: @Tadeu, eu não havia lido a definição da sua função cv, então não estava entendendo. Segue a solução! Pelo menos é assim que eu faria :D