# Linhas com cores alternatas para uma variavel categorica ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho uma base de dados com consumo de racao por animal e por dia.

Segue só uma parte da base para terem uma ideia:

```js
Animal Time Consumo
5 1 2.53396
5 2 2.32906
5 3 2.94379
5 4 3.36162
6 1 2.89082
6 2 2.53898
6 3 2.97881
6 4 3.03876
7 1 2.81885
7 2 2.73889
7 3 2.67891
7 4 2.87885
```

Quero gerar uma grafico no qual somente um dos animais (Ex: Animal=7) tenha cor da linha diferente (consumo em funcao do time) e os demais tenham a mesma cor. 
No ggplot consegui fazer um grafico para que todos os animais tenham a mesma cor, só nao consigo fazer uma linha para o animal 7 com cor diferente. Segue o comnado que usei:

```js
library(ggplot2)
Consumo$Animal <- factor(Consumo$Animal)
ggplot(data = Consumo, aes(x = Time, y = Consumo, colours=Animal)) +
  geom_line(color="grey") +
  xlab("Time, d") +
  ylab("Forecast daily feed intake,kg") +  
  theme_bw() +
  xlim(c(5, 80)) + 
  ylim(c(0, 5))+
  labs(title = "C: Current model") + theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold",size=18, hjust = 0))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14))
```

Segue abaixo o grafico que gerei com esse comando
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dados iniciais

```
texto <- 'Animal    Time    Consumo
5   1   2.53396
5   2   2.32906
5   3   2.94379
5   4   3.36162
6   1   2.89082
6   2   2.53898
6   3   2.97881
6   4   3.03876
7   1   2.81885
7   2   2.73889
7   3   2.67891
7   4   2.87885'

Consumo <- read.table(text = texto, header = TRUE)
Consumo$Animal <- factor(Consumo$Animal)
```

### Construindo o gráfico

Uma maneira simples de destacar determinado animal, digamos o "7", é criar uma variável que indica se aquela observação pertence ao grupo que vai ser destacado ou não. Pode ser algo simples como:

```
Consumo$especial <- ifelse(Consumo$Animal == '7', 'especial', 'normal')
```

E depois mapear a cor nesta variável.

```
library(ggplot2)
gg1 <- ggplot(data = Consumo, aes(x = Time, y = Consumo, colours=Animal)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = especial))
gg1
```

[image: gráfico básico]

Para tornas todos os casos cinzas e ressaltar apenas o grupo especial basta adicionar `scale_color_manual()`. A função `guides()` remove a legenda de cores.

```
gg2 <- gg1 +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(especial = 'red', normal = 'grey')) +
  guides(colour = 'none')
gg2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Gráfico final

Ao final o gráfico com o tema que você queria pode ser obtido com

```
gg2 + xlab("Time, d") +
  ylab("Forecast daily feed intake,kg") +  
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "C: Current model") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 18, hjust = 0),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Removi as funções de limite - `xlim()` e `ylim()` - do seu tema porque elas faziam os dados passados no exemplo sumirem.

Comment: Como eu poderia incluir uma nova linha nesse mesmo gráfico que representa o coeficiente de variacao entre os animais em funcao do tempo (time)? A ideia era colocar no segundo eixo nesse mesmo grafico. Eu seu calcular o CV pelo dplyr. Mas nao sei como inlcuir nesse grafico

Comment: Para calcular o CV, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206832/43953). E para incluir outro eixo [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/278434/43953).

Comment: Deu certo calcular o CV e gerar o grafico. Contudo, voce saberia me dizer como altero a fonte para Times no segundo eixo que foi criado? Todas as demais letras estao em Times, só no segundo eixo que esta arial

Comment: @LucianoHauschild Faça uma nova pergunta compartilhando o código de sua tentativa e o resultado esperado