# Plotar 2 graficos em um e eixos y com escalas diferentes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá, mestres da analise de dados

Estou com um problema em plotar dois graficos com diferentes escalas no eixo y, da esquerda representa unidade e o da direita representa Dia.

Tentei achar alguma informação sobre isso, a maior parte da informação que encontrei foi em alguns do stack US. Um desses posts usava esse código:

```
 scale_y_continuous( sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . /100, name = "Dia")
```

Pelo o que entendi, o ggplot2 não dá uma função pronta esse tipo de gráfico e tem que fazer uma gambiarra usando a configuração do eixo Y da esquerda também na direita, apenas reduizndo a os valores da esquerda em /100. Daí fiz esse código:

```
ggplot(tab.OpTT)+
 geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v1, group = 1), fill = "darkviolet")+
 geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v2, group = 1), fill = "violet", alpha = 
 0.7)+
 geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v3, group = 1), fill = "lightblue", alpha 
 = 0.8)+
 geom_line( data = tab.OpTT  %>% filter(y=="Dias"), aes(x = Dia, y = 
 TMR*100, group = 1), color = "darkblue", linetype=7)+
 geom_line( data = tab.OpTT  %>% filter(y=="Dias"), aes(x = Dia, y = 
 AME*100, group = 1), color = "pink", linetype = 5)+
 labs(x = "Período de 05/02 á 18/02", y = "Chamadas", title = "teste 5")+
 scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day"),  
 date_labels="%d/%b", minor_breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), 
 by="1 month"))+
 scale_y_continuous( sec.axis = sec_axis(~. /100, name = "Dia")+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
```

Mais frustrante é que quand executa essa linha que fiz anterior, nada ocorre ou nem dá algum erro.

tirei informação desses links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942002/geom-line-with-different-y-axis-scale

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855242/plot-with-2-y-axes-with-different-scale-on-a-single-plot-using-ggplot2

( este ultimo link é uma gabiarra master)

Comment: Infelizmente seu exemplo não é reproduzível. Por mais que tentemos usar os dados disponibilizados por você na sua [última dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277500/ordenamento-de-datas-ggplot2), o nome das variáveis não são os mesmos. Por favor, forneça seus dados, ou uma parte (utilize o comando `dput()`).

Comment: Rafael cunha, consegui resolver aqui e te agradeço por sua disposição. Para Material de dúvidas, vou elaborar um post completo falando como realizar esse ggplot para qualquer uma outra pessoa que possa ter a mesma dúvida no futuro.  Ps. Arrumarei os erros presentes no meu ultimo post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui sanar a minha dúvida.

A resolução que encontrei em site, realiza essa plotagem em `ggplot2` de um gráfico com dois eixos "y" e cada um deles com escalas diferentes. Recomendo também para quem teve o mesmo problema que eu tive (mais ainda quem irá usar em app web), tente primeiro o `googleVis`, por que é possivel realizar essa plotagem sem uso de "Gambiarras" e de um modo geral é mais fácil de fazer.

http://lehoangvan.com/posts/dual-y-axis-ggplot2/

(Link da resolução)

Neste caso, não irei detalhar a resolução, pois o site que citei tem uma melhor didática no passo a passo (infelizmente está em ingês) e disponibilizo meu código comentado para tirar qualquer dúvidas.

```
 #Bibliotecas necessárias
 library(lubridate)
 library(gtable)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(grid)
 library(extrafont)
 loadfonts(device="win")

 # Transformar var tab.OpTT$Dia em formato ymd (yyyy-mm-dd) do lubridate
 tab.OpTT$Dia <- seq(ymd("2018-01-19"), ymd("2018-02-18"), by="days")

 #Primeiro plot de gráfico, com eixo "Y" orientação na esquerda
 p1 <- ggplot(tab.OpTT)+
 geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v1, group = 1), fill = "#3D196D")+
 geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v2, group = 1), fill = "#B18AE4", alpha = 0.7)+
 geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v3, group = 1), fill = "#490F49", alpha = 0.8)+
 labs( x=NULL,y=NULL)+
 ggtitle("Chamadas\n")+
 scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day"),  
 date_labels="%d/%b", minor_breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), 
 by="1 month"))+  
 scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 200)) +
 theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.2))+                    
 theme(
     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
     panel.background = element_blank(), 
     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
     panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5), 
     panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
     text = element_text(family="Simplon BP Light"),
     axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),  
     axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
     axis.ticks.length = unit(.25, "cm"),
     axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "gray50"),
     axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
     plot.title = element_text(hjust = 3.00 , vjust= 1.00, color = "gray50", 
     size = 14, family = "Simplon BP Light")) 


 #Segundo plot de gráfico, com eixo "Y" orientação na direita.
 p2 <- ggplot(tab.OpTT)+
 geom_line(  aes(x = Dia, y = v4, group = 1), color = "#00008B", linetype= 1, size = 1.5)+
 geom_line(  aes(x = Dia, y = v5, group = 1), color = "#F4D0F4", linetype = 7, size = 1.5)+
 labs(x= NULL, y= NULL)+
 scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day"),  
 date_labels="%d/%b", minor_breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), 
 by="1 month"))+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+  
 scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-0, 15)) +
 theme(
     panel.border = element_blank(),
     panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
     panel.background = element_blank(),
     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
     panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
     text = element_text(family="Simplon BP Light"),
     axis.text.y = element_text(size=14),
     axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
     axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
     axis.ticks.length = unit(.25, "cm"),
     axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "gray50"),
     axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
     plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.6, vjust=2.12, color = "gray50", size = 14, family = "Simplon BP Light"))

     #inversor
     g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1)) # tranforma o ggplot em gtable e armazena na Var g1
     g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2)) # tranforma o ggplot em gtable e armazena na Var g2
     pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r)) #Pega as coordenadas do painel p1, para que o p2 seja posicionado corretamente
     g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, pp$l, pp$b, pp$l) #Sobrepoe o p2 encima do p1 
     ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l") #extrai o eixo "Y" da p2
     ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
     ax <- ga$children[[2]]
     ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths) # gira horizontamente o eixo "Y" da p2
     ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
     g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1) #Adiciona e vira o eixo "Y" da p2 para a direita
     g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)
     g$grobs[[8]]$children$GRID.text.1767$label <- c("Chamada\n", "Dia\n") 
     #vai add os titulos de forma certa
     g$grobs[[8]]$children$GRID.text.1767$gp$col <-c("#68382C","#00A4E6")g$grobs[[8]]$children$GRID.text.1767$x <- unit(c(-0.155, 0.829), "npc")
     grid.draw(g) #Executa o grid como gráfico
```

Os dados estão em um antigo post meu e não coloquei aqui para não ficar longo o post. Segue link para acessar: [Ordenamento de Datas ggplot2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277500/ordenamento-de-datas-ggplot2)

Resultado foi:

[image: gráfico certo]

Concluindo: o gráfico ainda não está pronto, ainda falta o título e as legendas. O objetivo dessa pergunta era de apenas o alinhamento, escala e formatação do gráfico. Portanto considero fechado.

A resolução está creditada ao usuário Kohske

http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2

Comment: Aplique esse procedimento e funcionou, contudo o segundo eixo criado esta com letra arial e os demais textos com Times. Nos graficos formatei para ter Times. Mas nesse segundo eixo criado nao sei como fazer isso

Comment: @LucianoHauschild , olha não me ocorreu esse erro de fonte. Veja que dei um merge em dois gráficos diferentes, portanto tive que setar a mesma aparência nos dois, se caso não tenha feito, recomendo que faça isso. Também veja se a Api   `library(extrafont)` está instalada ou ativada e se está realizando o comando  `loadfonts(device="win")` para dar load nas fonte no R.